# ng-grid with paging and selection checkbox

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I created an example based on the server side paging example on the ng-grid website. This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wytn3fZMA5uJyvmCYOjU?p=preview) has server side paging and selection checkbox enabled. However, if you use the header checkbox to select all the boxes and go to the next page the checkbox in the header stays checked. When you click it it will uncheck the previous set of rows. Is there a way to make this work for both server size paging and selection checkbox in the header?